# Replicate the Export to excel button in javascript for a JSOM app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, app, client-object-model

I have completed my first sharepoint 2013 app (sharepoint hosted) where I'm using my own code to display list data etc rather than use any OTB pages/functionality.

The one feature I want to include from the OTB ribbon is the export to excel feature but I can't see any examples of this on MSDN, has anyone managed to do this via Javascript or JQuery?

Thanks,

S

**For anyone interested this is how i did it!**

Function to get my lists and views

```
function getLists() {
lists = web.get_lists();
context.load(lists, "Include(Id, Title, Hidden, ItemCount, Views)");
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
}
```

Function to get list and build link

```
function onSuccess() {

var listsEnum = lists.getEnumerator();
while (listsEnum.moveNext()) {
    var list = listsEnum.get_current();

    if (list.get_title() == "Name of list") {
        var title = list.get_title();
        var viewCollection = list.get_views();
        var viewInfo = 'Tasks list current views: \n\n';
        var viewEnumerator = viewCollection.getEnumerator();
        while (viewEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var view = viewEnumerator.get_current();
            if (view.get_title() == "View-Title") {
                var viewGUID = view.get_id();
                //Add the export link
                $('#lnkExport').attr("href", "../_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=" + list.get_id().toString() + "&View=" + viewGUID + "&CacheControl=1");

            }

        }


    }


}


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this might help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/wkriebel/archive/2005/08/22/LinkToExportToSpreadsheet.aspx

Tested on SP2010

To replicate the funtionallity of "Export to Excel" (obtain the iqf file), all that needs to be done is replacing the place holders with your environment information in the following link:

**http://[Server]/[Site]/([Subsite]/)_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=[ListGUID]&View=[ViewGUID]&CacheControl=1**

**Example:**

http://example.net/dts/psronline/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=%7B1DBBD5FF%2DC452%2D412D%2D86F9%2DE3980F2F4EC4%7D&View=%7BF2E40BE2%2DB509%2D402E%2DBF7E%2DBC75907E9018%7D&CacheControl=1

Regards,
David

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. The answer will be of no help if the link breaks. Instead, add the important bits from the link to your answer (with a clearly visible source off-course)

Comment: Sure, i will edit the response.

Comment: You think this dll is available in 2013?

Comment: Yes, i don't have a SP 2013 environment available right now to test, but accordingly to this http://books.google.fr/books?id=DHHr4kV9dHcC&pg=PT59&lpg=PT59&dq=sharepoint+2013+export+to+excel+owssvr.dll&source=bl&ots=RYylQqqt-7&sig=Qvctn8EkPqtK48WqWns93r2BdBc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ijz7UprGL6nB0gW154DIDw&ved=0CDIQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=sharepoint%202013%20export%20to%20excel%20owssvr.dll&f=false it is available.

Comment: Ok had some time to look at this and i don't think this will work as we don't know the List or view guid until we deploy.

Comment: In that case i would simply create the link dynamically using CSOM - client side object model, just one pointer in that direction: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f74a4794-464b-4d5a-97a1-e6a7f651413f/get-list-guid-client-object-model (Get the list id)

Comment: I worked out how to do it by getting the list and view data. Updated the question with the answer. I've marked your answer as the answer as it did lead me to the eventual answer ;-)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: This OOB feature helped me to avoid implementing custom solution. Great. Thanks David.